# Run javascript on server and send DOM results to client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, dom

I've been stuck on this one for a while, so it's time to consult the pros.  I've created a charting application that uses javascript to do heavy DOM manipulation/generation on the client (creating barcharts made of colored divs, etc).

Long story short, I want to avoid sending my js library to the client.  Is there any way to create the content on the server, using my existing javascript library, and only send the javascript-generated HTML to the client?

Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Maybe, if you're ready to install a server-side JavaScript interpreter, but it will probably turn out to be too complex because there is no DOM present on server side (but I don't know for sure, I've never done server side Javascript before)

Comment: Maybe you should consider rewrite your js library into a server side script...

Comment: @lonut - 
Right -- that's what I'm trying to avoid by asking this question.

Comment: Why would you want to use your server to handle that process for each request and potentially strain your resources?

Comment: @mjw06d - because the JS library is my intellectual property and main revenue generator. Also, server load isn't an issue at this point...but hopefully one day it will be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) will likely do what you want, it has been used to do [DOM manipulation with YUI3](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/05/running-yui-3-server-side-with-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your JavaScript DOM code to Java W3C DOM on [ItsNat](http://www.itsnat.org), for instance, take a look to [this example](http://www.innowhere.com:8080/inexperiments/inexpservlet?itsnat_doc_name=waiaria_tree). Umm is based on Java not .Net.